# ttkbootstrap module not found

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, ttkbootstrap

I recently installed pip install ttkbootstrap successfully. I also have tkinter installed and everything works fine when I import it. When I try to import ttkbootstrap into PyCharm it doesnt recognize the module and gives me this error:
File "C:\Coding\PyCharm\Projects\Project 1\projectfile.py", line 3, in 
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttkbootstrap'

I've searched other questions and couldn't find an answer to this problem. I was wondering if anyone knows what to do here, I've been struggling with this for a while now, any help would be be really appreciated

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python on your system?

Comment: when i check it says i have 3.12.1 installed. idk how to check for multiple versions

Comment: What do you see when you enter the command `py -m pip show ttkbootstrap`?

Comment: C:\Users\besne>py -m pip show ttkbootstrap
Name: ttkbootstrap
Version: 1.10.1
Summary: A supercharged theme extension for tkinter that enables on-demand modern flat style themes inspired by Bootstrap.
Home-page: https://github.com/israel-dryer/ttkbootstrap
Author: Israel Dryer
Author-email: israel.dryer@gmail.com
License:
Location: C:\Users\besne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires: pillow
Required-by:

Comment: This almost certainly means that pycharm is using a different version of python than what you get from the command line.

Comment: I have to agree with @BryanOakley. I'm not familiar with PyCharm, but I know VS Code lets you select your Python interpreter if you have more than one version installed. Perhaps someone with PyCharm experience can weigh in if something similar exists there? To clarify: you'll need to tell PyCharm to use the same version of Python that runs when you call `pip` (which in your case appears to be 3.12)

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) for how to set up interpreters / virtual environments in PyCharm - it might be worth a look!

Comment: Thanks I was at work all day but Ill look into it now. If i keep having issues with PyCharm i might give VSCode a try.

Comment: This work for me. `from tkinter import Tk`. instead of `tk`.

Comment: You need to update PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I create a new project I also create a venv from one of my interpreters on my system.

[image: new pycharm project]

In this venv you then install ttkbootstrap in the settings of PyCharm.

[image: pycharm settings install ttkbootstrap]

If you want to test if the installation worked you'll have to either use the temrminal inside PyCharm or just use the import statement.

[image: import statement]

[image: terminal in pycharm]

You can even have multiple run configurations including different python interpreters and as you install them as venv you can have multiple installations of packages in these environments.

[image: debug run configs]

**Important: If you are running Python 3.12 in PyCharm you'll have to update to the latest version. After this you'll probably have to recreate your venv otherwise it will still not work**

Comment: I ended up using VSCode and everything worked fine. I don't know why but pycharm was only letting me use python 3.10. Thanks for the reply though I wouldn't have noticed something was off with my pycharm if it wasn't for this post.

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, did you happen to update PyCharm and still have the same problem? Python 3.12 would not run on older versions of PyCharm

Comment: When I checked for updates on pycharm it said i was running the lastest version. Other than that i have no idea to be honest

Comment: I got this error in VS code. It turned out I had created the .venv beforehand.  Once I deleted the virtual environment and recreated it ttkbootstrap worked.

Comment: This is right and the same for PyCharm. After updating to the latest version you might have to recreate the venv to properly work at least if the problem was python 3.12 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

script:

```
from ttkbootstrap import Style 
from tkinter import Tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
 

style = Tk() 
window = style.master

ttk.Label(style, text='my label' ).pack()
 
style.mainloop()
```

Or same module.

```
root = Tk()

ttk.Label(root, text='my label').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]